# Shader with golden logo, normal map and or displacement map

Tags: materials, shaders

Hi all you shader experts out there!

I would like to set up a shader/material with the following ingredients:

1. A base wood texture with a normal map and preferably a displacement map to add some realistic wood structure.
2. A logo/graphic that is reflective gold, and that is affected by the normal map/displacement map at the same time.

So far, I've been able to produce a shader with the wood texture, normal map and a logo on it. No displacement map, though:

[image: Logo on wood setup]

I've also managed to set a gold logo material with transparency:

[image: go]

I guess there's a really easy setup to achieve this, but...please help me out here!

Comment: Assuming the logo is an image with a transparent background, you could use it as the factor for mixing two shaders, one with the bare wood material and the other for the gold writing. You can then use the same bump map on both shaders pre- or post-mixing.

Comment: you need to use one material only, mix your first nodes with the second ones into a Mix Shader, if you have a transparent background behind your text, plug the alpha output of the Image Texture node into the Factor of the Mix Shader

Comment: @Morpheu5 :  Thank you! I'll try it out!

Comment: @moonboots : Oh, I think I follow you. But can you please make a quick node setup for it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make one and unique material with this kind of node organisation (very simplified). You need to use the logo alpha output into the factor of the *Mix Shader* in order to make a mask and see the background. Of course the left part can be as complicated as you want, with *Bump* or *Normal* nodes plugged into the normal socket of the *Diffuse* etc:

[image]